# How do I verify the file signature using only the public certificate with openssl?

Tags: powershell, cmd, openssl

I have to verify the signature in a file (signedFile.txt) that was signed with the private key. I only have access to the public certificate (.cer) that was generated from the private key if I'm not wrong.I'm using poweshell but to simplify I post this using cmd commands and openssl.

This the certificate that I have:
[certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcGhb.png)

Usig theses post as a guide [x509 Certificate Manual Signature Verification](https://linuxctl.com/2017/02/x509-certificate-manual-signature-verification/) and [RSA sign and verify using Openssl : Behind the scene](https://medium.com/@bn121rajesh/rsa-sign-and-verify-using-openssl-behind-the-scene-bf3cac0aade2)

**Using cmd I pass the .cer file to .pem**

```
openssl x509  -inform DER -outform PEM -in myCert.cer -pubkey -out myCertPem.pem
```

**After that I got the public key from the certificate using the next command:**

```
openssl x509 -in myCertPem.pem -noout -pubkey > myPubKey.pem
```

I got

[public key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQzqt.png)

**Usig this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261393/x-509-certificate-signature-extraction) I extrated the Signature Algorithm from the certificate**

```
openssl x509 -in certPEMSAT.pem -text -noout -certopt ca_default -certopt no_validity -certopt no_serial -certopt no_subject -certopt no_extensions -certopt no_signame > sign.txt.sha256
```

[Signature Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjQGN.png)

EDIT 1

using powershell I was able to clean and dump it to binary

```
$sign = get-content sign.txt.sha256 | select-string -Pattern 'Signature 
Algorithm' -NotMatch | Out-File newSignature.txt
$sign = (get-content newSignature.txt) -join ' ' 
$sign = $sign -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+',' '
Set-Content signBytes.bin $sign | Format-Hex
```

[Signature binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mzgv.png)

Finally, it's just matter of using the following command:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify myPubKey.pem -signature signBytes.bin signedFile.txt
```

I know that I have to transform the hex signature into a binary signature prior to verification [according this page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/dgst.1ssl.html), but this is where I'm stuck.

I'm still getting verify failed

Comment: You mention `signedFile.txt`, does that contain both the text as well as the signature? If yes, how is it formatted? If no, where exactly does the text reside and where does the signature reside?

Comment: If you're using PowerShell, can you simply use `(Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath .\signedFile.txt).Status`, 
`(Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath .\signedFile.txt).SignerCertificate.Verify()`, and 
`(Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath .\signedFile.txt).TimeStamperCertificate.Verify()` ?  Otherwise, for simplicity, perhaps download (free) [signtool.exe from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/using-signtool-to-verify-a-file-signature?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to verify signatures.  Worth a mention.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek the signedFile.txt is the file that contains information and was signed by the certificate

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you extracted digital signature from the certificate and trying to verify some arbitrary file signature. This wont work.

To verify file signature you need target file, it's signature and the public key.

You already got the public key considering your file is signed with the private key of certificate you provided, so openssl command would be this:

```
openssl dgst -sha512 -verify myPubKey.pem -signature signedFile.sig signedFile.txt
```